# Which test frameworks don't replace "new" and "malloc"?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, operator-overloading

In my current project I use my own custom allocators inspired by the [article on BitSquid](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2010/09/custom-memory-allocation-in-c.html). I also replace new and malloc to help me track down where they are used (as this should be minimised - currently not called anywhere.)

I've read that many of the more mature C++ test frameworks (CppUTest for example) rely on their own new/malloc overloads. Are there any out there that don't? My project is cross-platform (Windows, Linux, Mac and mobiles) if that helps.

(Edit: Initially forgot to mention that we don't use Boost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost Tests for example does not base itself on his own new/malloc overloads, I actually use BOOST TESTS and I have created new/malloc overloads to see where (line and file) memory leek happens.

BOOST is cross platform but since I do all my development on windows I used some prexistent overloads of malloc-like functions (**crtdbg.h**) and just overloaded the new operator. If you need your tests to be cross platform you can overload the mallocs manually.

the code below is the content of a **.h** file that is the last included file of every **.cpp** file.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW

#endif
```

I used this approach because some parts of boost (not the testing part) overload the new operator and I also have another library that internaly overloads the new operator so by including this at the end of the includes list I am sure that I do not mess with the internals of my libraries.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Defining a macro called `new` is technically forbidden by the standard.

Comment: As you can see I only do it in DEBUG mode (my release code does not do anything like that) and I find that it is the best method to find the place where a memory leek happens.
It is not very useful if you only know the address in memory of the object that was allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ha11owed. Unfortunately I forgot to mention in the question that we don't use Boost - otherwise a good suggestion. While I have done in the past for smart pointers/threading, we aren't using it for the current project for multiple reasons (e.g.  performance hit when using shared_ptr vs a plain old * - yes we have profiled our code).

Comment: You can still use BOOST only for your tests project. You don't even need to import boost as a dependency to your project if your testing is done in a separate project. Also either way you go you will have a dependency to a external library (BOOST, CppUTest ...).

Comment: I actually have a bundle of C++/C# projects, some of them use some libraries, some don't, but for unit testing I have a separate project that has boost as dependency.

Comment: Slaps forehead! Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that, given that I use separate test projects in C#/Java (not to mention the 9 already in the current solution). I'll check out Boost Tests. Definitely need to drink coffee before coming on here in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking to include Boost or new library and you just want to make sure allocations/de-allocations are happening properly. Follow these steps.
1. Overload your new.
2. Add a reference counting mechanism in your overloaded new.
3. In your test case use assert to check reference counts at start and end.

This might seem like a simple setup but will eliminate lots of possible leaks in unit testing itself.

Comment: In theory the reference counts should always be zero as I want all allocations to use my IAllocator->allocate(size, alignment) methods (and an initial allocation from the OS through VirtualAlloc or similar). To help guard against other allocations I already do something similar to your suggestion.